# Compiling a kernel for Gentoo with my module list from Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, gentoo, chroot, xubuntu

A while ago, I started installing Gentoo on my Xubuntu box, using a chroot from Xubuntu, following these guides: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64 http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Gentoo-Linux-from-Ubuntu

I decided to bootstrap my Gentoo install following instructions outlined in the Gentoo FAQ, and after some minor difficulties, I managed to succeed.

Now, I'm trying to compile myself a kernel for my gentoo install, and I'm trying to go small, speedy, and minimal. I only want it to select the appropriate driver modules for the devices I have installed, but I don't know if I'll be able to get it to select those modules from the confines of a chroot.

Is there a way I could generate a kernel module list in Ubuntu, then do the kernel compiling on Gentoo so it's done with my bootstrapped toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

Copy one of /proc/config, /proc/config.gz, /boot/config-$(uname -r) from your ubuntu installation as .config inside the /usr/src/linux/. Then make oldconfig, and continue as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the [Kernel Installation Chapter](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel) in the Wiki, and build the Kernel inside the chroot.  Doing otherwise will prevent the system from booting when finished.  If you aren't comfortable building a kernel manually, please follow the Alternative: Using genkernel in Section 3 of said Wiki